# To Get Some lines from indx.html to another text.html

Tags: javascript

With the help of following code i will get the 100% ok result but if i need to trigger the same as automatic how it is possible.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>reading file</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var reader = new FileReader();

            function readText(that){

                if(that.files && that.files[0]){
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var output=e.target.result;
                        //process text to show only lines with "li class="Body-P-P1":
                output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /\li class="Body-P-P1"/).join("\n");

                    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= output;
                    };//end onload()
                    reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);
                }//end if html5 filelist support
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
        <div id="main"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Kindly let me know the way i run the above code automatically trigger whenever i click on any programe which contain the same code.